# Is there any way to create more clarity in my JavaFX code?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, lambda, eventhandler

I'm in the first year of my computer science study, and I just got my first project in which I have to create an application that can perform CRUD operations on an SQL database. This application needs to have a GUI, for which we are required to use JavaFX.

Currently I'm very unsure about the way I am handling button clicks. For instance, the main screen has three buttons (Accounts, Profiles, Watched), each of which will create a new Scene with three more buttons (Create, Edit, Delete). This results in a lot of lambda expressions nested in each other, which makes the code very messy to look at. Below you will see a part of my code:

```
public class GUI extends Application {

    Database db = new Database();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // Three buttons and a Label for the first scene.
        Button buttonAccounts = new Button("Accounts");
        Button buttonProfiles = new Button("Profiles");
        Button buttonWatched = new Button("Watched");
        Label pickAnOption = new Label("Pick an option:");

        // Two HBoxes, first one for the Label, the other one for the three Buttons.
        // Both HBoxes are aligned in the center.
        HBox options = new HBox(12);
        options.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        options.getChildren().addAll(buttonAccounts, buttonProfiles, buttonWatched);
        HBox text = new HBox();
        text.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        text.getChildren().add(pickAnOption);

        // The HBoxes are placed in a BorderPane.
        // HBox "text" has a top margin of 20 and HBox "options" has a bottom margin of 20.
        // This way, the BorderPane will be nicely aligned in the middle of the scene.
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setTop(text);
        pane.setMargin(text, new Insets(20, 0, 0 , 0));
        pane.setCenter(options);
        pane.setMargin(options, new Insets(0, 0, 20, 0));

        Scene selectionScreen = new Scene(pane, 500, 100);

        stage.setTitle("Netflix Statistix door S. Jaspers, I. Moerenhout en Z. Usmaeva");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(selectionScreen);
        stage.show();

        // EventHandler for the Accounts Button.
        buttonAccounts.setOnAction(e -> {
            Button buttonCreateAccount = new Button("Create");
            Button buttonEditAccount = new Button("Edit");
            Button buttonDeleteAccount = new Button("Delete");
            Button back = new Button("Back");
            Label createEditOrDelete = new Label("Create a new account, or edit/delete an existing account:");

            back.setOnAction(e1 -> stage.setScene(selectionScreen));

            HBox text1 = new HBox();
            text1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            text1.getChildren().add(createEditOrDelete);
            HBox options1 = new HBox(12);
            options1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            options1.getChildren().addAll(buttonCreateAccount, buttonEditAccount, buttonDeleteAccount);
            HBox text2 = new HBox();
            text2.setSpacing(50);
            text2.getChildren().add(back);

            BorderPane pane1 = new BorderPane();
            pane1.setTop(text1);
            pane1.setMargin(text1, new Insets(15, 0, 0, 0));
            pane1.setCenter(options1);
            pane1.setMargin(options1, new Insets(0, 0, 15, 0));
            pane1.setBottom(text2);

            Scene accounts = new Scene(pane1, 500, 100);
            stage.setScene(accounts);

            // EventHandler for the Create Account button.
            buttonCreateAccount.setOnAction(e1 -> {
                GridPane grid = new GridPane();
                grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
                grid.setVgap(8);
                grid.setHgap(10);

                Button buttonSave = new Button("Save");
                Button buttonCancel = new Button("Cancel");

                buttonCancel.setOnAction(e3 -> {
                    stage.setScene(accounts);
                });

                Label accountName = new Label("Name:");
                Label accountAddress = new Label("Address:");
                Label accountCity = new Label("City:");

                TextField accountNameInput = new TextField();
                TextField accountAddressInput = new TextField();
                TextField accountCityInput = new TextField();

                grid.add(accountName, 0, 0);
                grid.add(accountNameInput, 1, 0);
                grid.add(accountAddress, 0, 1);
                grid.add(accountAddressInput, 1, 1);
                grid.add(accountCity, 0, 2);
                grid.add(accountCityInput, 1, 2);
                grid.add(buttonSave, 2, 3);
                grid.add(buttonCancel, 3, 3);

                Scene accountCreation = new Scene(grid);
                stage.setScene(accountCreation);

                buttonSave.setOnAction(e2 -> {
                    boolean succeeded = db.createAccount(accountNameInput.getText(), accountAddressInput.getText(), accountCityInput.getText());
                    if (succeeded) {
                        new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Account successfully created.").show();
                    } else {
                        new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING, "Failed to create account.").show();
                    }
                });
            });
```

I'm still fairly new to JavaFX, and I was wondering if there is any way to make this code clearer. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Make a couple of classes, `button.setOnAction(evt -> stage.setScene(new EditScene());`. (Not necessarily in this way, I often use non-JavaFX classes and pass the stage.)

Comment: Or at least, move your button actions to private methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd love to post this as a comment, but I can't. Have you checked out FXML?
It allows you to set properties in a very clean and simple way. If you want autocompletion and inspections then I recommend IntelliJ IDEA. Here's a nice article which explains the benefits of FXML: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/why_use_fxml.htm

Answer (score 1):

1. You can make your `GUI` class implement the [EventHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html) interface. Then you can write the following in your code:

```java
buttonAccounts.setOnAction(this);
```

The parameter of the `handle()` method contains the source of the event, i.e. the button that was clicked. Your code would look something like the following:

```java
public class GUI extends Application implements EventHandler<Action> {
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == buttonAccounts) {
            // Handle it.
        }
        else if (source == buttonEditAccount) {
        }
        // etc.
    }
}
```

2. You can use [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). Write a method that takes a single `ActionEvent` parameter and returns `void`, e.g.

```java
private void handleButtons(ActionEvent event) {
    Object source = event.getSource();
    // As above.
}
```

Then you can write...

```java
buttonAccounts.setOnAction(this::handleButtons);
```

Comment: IMO, implementing the EventHandler interface in Application violates the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [seperation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). For any non-trivial application (e.g. an app with database interaction), the Application class should only implement the application lifecycle, as described in the [Application javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html), all else should be delegated to other classes.

Comment: I also think shared event handlers such as described here are a bad idea.  Just define a different event handler for each different event source and set it directly on the node receiving the event, rather than a single event handler which tests the source, then switches its functionality based on the source.